# How can I send SMS using sendTextMessage

Tags: android, sms

I make simple function to send SMS.

```
public void send(String address, String packet){//address="13614951242" packet="a"
    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sm.sendTextMessage(address, null, packet, null, null);
}
```

But, There is NullPointException Bug.

```
10-12 03:20:05.463: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9662): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 03:20:05.463: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9662):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1253)
10-12 03:20:05.463: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9662):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
10-12 03:20:05.463: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9662):     at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:561)
10-12 03:20:05.463: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9662):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:109)
10-12 03:20:05.463: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9662):     at ric.FPSProject.SinglePos.SinglePosMap.initPersonData(SinglePosMap.java:260)
10-12 03:20:05.463: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9662):     at ric.FPSProject.SinglePos.SinglePosMap.onResume(SinglePosMap.java:160)
10-12 03:20:05.463: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9662):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1151)
10-12 03:20:05.463: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9662):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
10-12 03:20:05.463: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9662):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3123)
10-12 03:20:05.463: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9662):     ... 12 more
```

What's wrong? Help me!

Comment: Can you please give us some more information? Is there anything else in the logcat output regarding this error?

Comment: This is being run on a phone WITH SMS capabilities, correct?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832864/sendtextmessage-in-android-phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to have your application send the SMS or are you trying to open the default SMS application to send the SMS?  If you are trying to do the later all you need to do is:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("sms:"));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("sms_body", "your string here"); 
startActivity(i);
```

This will open the default sms with the "your string here" string in the message body.

Answer (score 0):

Well, worked for me, so I guess you have a bug somewhere else. This is what I tried:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Playground extends Activity {
    Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                send("13614951242", "a");
            }
        });
    }

    private void send(String number, String message) {
        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, so there must be an issue elsewhere.  Make sure you have the following permissions in your Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```