# sendTextMessage In android phone

Tags: android, sms

This is simple code send SMS.

```
47: SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
48: sms.sendTextMessage("12345678901", null, "hello!", null, null);
```

But I can't run this code.
This code run success in android version 2.1, but my phone, Samsung galaxy II, it occur NullPointException error. Tell me about that problem. Here is AndroidManifest.xml code and error log.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {ric.FPSProject.FamilyPositionSearch/ric.FPSProject.SinglePos.SinglePosMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2668)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1253)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:561)
  at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:109)
  **at ric.FPSProject.SinglePos.SinglePosMap.sendSMS(SinglePosMap.java:48)**
  at ric.FPSProject.SinglePos.SinglePosMap.initPersonData(SinglePosMap.java:273)
  at ric.FPSProject.SinglePos.SinglePosMap.onCreate(SinglePosMap.java:134)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2632)
  ... 11 more
```

Comment: I tried the code, and it worked for me (although I did replace the phone number to a valid phone number). Please paste more lines from the logcat output, that might help locating the problem.

Comment: Ok, I will, and please help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give the pending intent in your 48th line as given bellow

```
String sent = "android.telephony.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_SENT";
PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(smsActivity.this, 0,new Intent(sent), 0);

sms.sendTextMessage("12345678901", null, "hello!", piSent, null);
```

am sure it works :)

Answer (score 4):

This Problem also Occurs when your msg length exceeds normal text msg length(i.e 160 Character) you need to divide the msg into parts and send... Use this code it may help you

```
public static void sendSms(Activity curActivity, String phoneNumber, String msg) {
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault(); 

 ArrayList<String> msgStringArray = smsManager.divideMessage(msg);      

 smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, msgStringArray, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using special characters in the SMS Message. Changing to normal english characters worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Null Exception is in the SMS lenght, you may use

```
try {}catch(Exception ex) {}
```

in your code in case you get null exception and try send "divided" sms using:

```
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(telephone, null, parts, null, null);
```

Comment: is there any advantage between sending it normally and catching vs just always dividing and sending?