# sendTextMessage to send SMS

Tags: android, sms

I want send SMS using sendTextMessage() method in my app...

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

...but the NullPointerException error occurs.

I use Galaxy SII and I use it in China.

The SMSC number can be reason of this mistake or other mistake? what's wrong? help me.

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sendTextMessage In android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832864/sendtextmessage-in-android-phone)

Comment: The documentation doesn't show that sendTextMessage throws NullPointerException (Atleast if phoneNumber and message are not null). At which line did you get it?

Comment: can you post a stack trace? I'm going to (at this point) assume that either the phoneNumber or message are null

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me (using Galaxy S II in the United States).  One note...you don't need the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.