# android app is not sending sms automatically on real device

Tags: android, sms

I have developed an android app that automatically sends an SMS automatically to a device from which it receives an SMS.

My App is working fine on the emulator but when I run it on a real device (android mobile) then it only receives SMSs and does not sends a reponse automatically.

My code is as follows.

```
public class SMSReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String address;
    String smsMe = "I Recieved Your SMS";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
            smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
            address = smsMessage[n].getOriginatingAddress();
        }

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"Received SMS: " +
                 smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(address, null, smsMe, null, null);
    }
}
```

I don't know what is the problem. And why it is not working properly on a real device.

Comment: Permissions in your Manifest file? Have you declared them?

Comment: @Shalini Version of real device is 2.2 froyo and Also I have developed   the application on the same version on emulator.

Comment: @Dya Yes Dya I have declared the permissions for SEND_SMS and also for RECIEVE_SMS.

Comment: hmm, just check if the value of your "address" variable is as expected (just before u send the sms). Print it to the logcat and check.

Comment: @Dya I have checked value of "address" and it is correct as expected(mobile no.).

Comment: Check on a different device also, just to make sure the problem isn't device specific. And see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to send sms.

```
//---sends an SMS---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, class_name.class), 0);                
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
}
```

}

Comment: I require to make this function in activity class. and when I am calling this function from SMSReciever class using this SMSActivity sa=new SMSActivity(); sa.sendSMS(address, sms); It is giving java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Or u can create a separate class which has only this method in it. Then create an instance of that class here, and call this function. It should work. It has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added permissions to send SMS'es to your `AndroidManifest.xml`-file?

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

These are [related permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html):

```
SEND_SMS        Allows an application to send SMS messages.
BROADCAST_SMS   Allows an application to broadcast an SMS receipt notification
READ_SMS        Allows an application to read SMS messages.
RECEIVE_SMS     Allows an application to monitor incoming SMS messages, to record or perform processing on them.
WRITE_SMS       Allows an application to write SMS messages.
```

---

As [Dya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12263324/1380710) suggests, using [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)s, will make it possible to debug the action on your [`sendTextMessage()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

The error codes are as follows:

```
Activity.RESULT_OK
Activity.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE
Activity.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF
Activity.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU
```

---

According to [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/) (and [Mo Al Sh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12262998/1380710)) there's another built in way of sending SMS'es you could try:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content"); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Yes Thanks for your reply I have added both permissions <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/> in my AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: @geeta Okay, are you using the `android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager` or the `android.telephony.SmsManager`? The first mentioned is deprecated.

Comment: I am using android.telephony.SmsManager should I use android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager?

Comment: @geeta No, you're using the right one. Are you getting an exception when running the code or is it just the receiver not getting the SMS?
EDIT: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7833207/1380710

Comment: My app is not giving any exception It is showing the Toast message on the app screen like Received SMS: but the sender is not getting any reply message i.e "I Recieved Your SMS".

Comment: @geeta Have you tried the solution I linked to, or the other two suggestions that have been posted here?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that u have make entry in *manifest.xml* as;

```
<receiver android:name=".ListenerSms">
   <intent-filter ><action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have SMS permission

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"

in your manifest file ?

also you can try built in SMS application :

> ```
> Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
> ```
>
> sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content");
>
> sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
>
> startActivity(sendIntent);

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to send the message is because you have not included:

```
message_sc_address sms.sendTextMessage(address, message_sc_address, smsMe, null, null);
```

You can get this message address from your tablet/phone message section.