# XDK, sendSMS not working on Android Jelly Bean

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-3, intel-xdk

Im developing apps on Android with XDK Intel. and i can send sms via apps.
This is my code

```
function sendNow(){
   var xx=document.getElementById("dd").value;
   intel.xdk.device.sendSMS("Hallo hallo", xx);
}
// input id dd and onclick to sendNow
```

And this code not working on Android

Comment: Are you sure that `xx` contains a phone number?

Comment: what is the error you have received and BTW, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12263324/1533666

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendNow(){
    var xx=document.getElementById("dd").value;
    intel.xdk.device.sendSMS("Message", "XXXXXXXXX");
}
```