# Android Send SMS more than 160 characters

Tags: android, sms

Hi I am trying to send sms to different mobile numbers with different text body, my code is also sending sms more than 160 characters but it sends to only one number not to all , Now I want to send multiparttext message to all contact list.pls help

```
private void sendSMS()

{

 if (list_phone.size()!=0){

        //new AddNewCategory().execute();
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++){


    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();  
    ArrayList<String> message_parts = sm.divideMessage(list_MESSAGE_BODY.get(i));

   // Log.e("Message parts 3", message_parts.get(3));
   // Log.e("Message parts 4", message_parts.get(4));
    Intent iSent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iSent, 0);
    Intent iDel = new Intent();
    PendingIntent piDel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iDel, 0);

    if (message_parts.size() == 1)
    {
        String msg = message_parts.get(0);
        sm.sendTextMessage(list_phone.get(i), null, msg, piSent, piDel);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();      
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> delPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();       

        int ct = message_parts.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < ct; i++)
        {
            sentPis.add(i, piSent);
            delPis.add(i, piDel);
        }
        //Log.e("Message Parts", message_parts+"");
        Log.e("Phone list", list_phone.get(i));
        Log.e("Message parts"+i, message_parts.get(i));
        sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(list_phone.get(i), null, message_parts, sentPis, delPis);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

    }   
    }
    else
    {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone list is empty.. Message not sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }



}
```

Comment: The last time this was posted, one of the answers showed that you need to change the counter variable for at least one of the for-loops. Did you try that? Also, if that's the code [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823578/sms-application-gives-an-error-when-i-send-long-messege/22824203#22824203), you should only need to create one loop that iterates over the addressees and calls that method once for each message. You shouldn't have to change the code in that answer.

Comment: B M thanks for your reply. I had tried to change variables in program counter but the result is still disappointed .

Comment: You should only need to create a loop for the number of messages to send, and call `sendSMS(list_phone.get(i), list_MESSAGE_BODY.get(i))`, with that method as it appears in that linked answer.

Comment: code working fine for short messages but it sends long sms to only one number , I am calling sendSMS(list_phone.get(i), list_MESSAGE_BODY.get(i)) in time handler. pls look this one

Comment: first time it shows generic failure then sms sent