# SMS Sending issues in android kitkat

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am getting this issue most of the time in samsung devices while sending sms.

Android version
    **Android 4.0.3 - 4.0.4**

This is the error report I'm getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1333)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:644)
at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:149)
at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:99)
at com.msh7.utilities.SMSSender$SMSProgressTask.doInBackground(SMSSender.java:87)
at com.msh7.utilities.SMSSender$SMSProgressTask.doInBackground(SMSSender.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 5 more
```

On line 87, I have this code

```
sms.sendTextMessage(destinationNumber, null, msg, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

and all this method is inside the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` method.

Could anyone please help me in this?

*Note : My App sends sms in the background and it's not a default sms app.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832864/sendtextmessage-in-android-phone see answers there. Or see copy and pasted answers below :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's due to over size limit of text. Max allowed characters are 159. So you have to divide message into parts and send it.

Answer (score 0):

Dude you are getting NullPointerException. Seems like you have not initialized sms object.
Please check..